# Why can ids not be ported from Objective-C to Swift via struct?

Tags: swift, objective-c, struct

If I define an Objective-C `id`, in a `struct` in a header file:

```
struct MyStruct {
    id field;
};
struct MyStruct *_Nonnull myFunction(void);
```

Then I `#include` this header into the bridging header then attempt to use `myFunction()` from the Swift side, it will return `OpaquePointer`. If I attempt to return `MyStruct` directly, it will error saying `myFunction` is not defined. This only occurs if `MyStruct` contains an Objective-C `id`.

What is strange is if I declare a normal variable of type `id`, it can be ported to Swift just fine.

Why does Swift refuse **structs** containing Objective-C `id`s and what should I do to circumvent this?

Comment: Interestingly, if you have an Objective-C class with an `id` property it works just fine. Must be something about `id` in a `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swift can't handle strong references in structs.](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-make-c-struct-with-dispatch-queue-t-member-accessible-in-swift/29866/4) It can't insert the required retains/releases.

You need to tell Swift it doesn't have to by marking the field `__unsafe_unretained`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained id field;
};
```

With that, it will be imported normally, but `field` will be `Unmanaged`, which means you'll need to handle memory management yourself as needed.

Note that if this code is also called from ObjC, then this will change its memory management there, too. As discussed in the thread, you may need to check for the `__swift__` define to check what language is compiling this header.